# How to get clicked cell id in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get id of cell when clicking on it.
That's how i'm printing my table

```
public function DrawBoard(){        
            echo '<table id="board">';
            $i = 0;

            for($row= 0; $row < 8; $row++)
            {
                echo '<tr>';

                for($col= 0; $col < 8; $col++){            

                    if($this->fields[$row][$col] != 'e')
                    {
                        echo '<td id="'.$i.'">' . $this->fields[$row][$col] . '</td>';
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<td id="'.$i.'"></td>';
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            } 
            echo '</table>'; 
        }
```

This is my code to detect click events and send value to php

```
    $('#board td').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var fieldValue = $(this).html();
   
    $(this).css("background-color","green");

    $.post('models/board.php', {'id': id}, function(id){
        });
    });
```

And i want to print in alert this id

```
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$id');</script>";
        }
```

But nothing happens

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  I wouldn't expect anything to "happen" in the UI because the callback in the `$.post()` operation contains no code.

Comment: response is 200

Comment: And does the response contain the content you expect?  When you debug, what is the exact problem?  What is the goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Response contains proper id but i want to use this id in php but my php code doesn't work i have no errors

Comment: So the response body contains the ID value inside the `alert()`?

Comment: yes, here u can see the value is proper https://forum.pasja-informatyki.pl/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=11305137640802472059

Comment: That's not the response body, and it in no way validates what you're claiming.  Please take some time to look through the information available to you in your browser's debugging tools.  There's more on your screen than that one cropped screenshot.  In Chrome, just above that screenshot, there is a tab called "Response".  That contains the response body.

Comment: response tab: https://forum.pasja-informatyki.pl/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=13092491534604970647

Comment: If that's the response to your AJAX request then there's more to this than the code you're showing.  The code shown outputs *only* a single `<script>` element, but as you can see in that response there is entirely different content than that one element.

Comment: in answer i pasted my code without css file

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here...

- It's not entirely clear what it is you want/expect to happen...
- I'm not sure why you're sending this request to a `PHP` file containing a `class` definition?
- Your `PHP` file starts by outputting the contents of a style sheet. So it doesn't return `JS` and definitely doesn't only return the line you *expect*

That being said, depending what your intentions actually are, here is a starting point:

**Simply `alert` the `id` on success**

There's no need to read the `id` back from `PHP` when it's already on the page you're running your request from anyway!

```
$('#board td').on('click', function(response){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var fieldValue = $(this).html();

    $(this).css("background-color","green");

    $.post('models/board.php', {'id': id}, function(id){
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

**Run JS on success**

If you want to run some `JS` that is returned by the server then this is the way to do it...

Update your `post`:

```
$.post('models/board.php', {'id': id}, function(id){}, "script");
```

Make sure your `PHP` only outputs `JS`:

```
echo "alert({$_POST["id"]});
```

Comment: @NoobXDDD Then you can send it back as per the second part of the answer? You just have to make sure that you aren't outputting the style sheet along with it (and you don't need the script tags)

Comment: how to block style sheet from sending

Comment: @NoobXDDD Remove it from the code? What else is in the file?

Comment: i removed 
<style>
    <?php include 'CSS/board.css'; ?>
</style> 
now it works thanks for the help <3

Comment: @NoobXDDD No problem!